# How to increment a child model value in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, find, increment

Hello stackoverflowers!!!!

I have 2 models:

**models/user.rb**

```
class User
  has_many :colleagues

  before_save :give_points

  private

  def give_points
    if self.name == "Jordie"
      colleague1 = Colleague.find_by_name("Ann")
      colleague2 = Colleague.find_by_name("Beth")
      colleague1.increment!(:bonus, by = self.points)
      colleague1.decrement!(:bonus, by = self.points)
    end
  end
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class Colleague
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Matter fact I want to increment and decrement Ann and Beth when the Jordie gives them bonuses.But I get the following:

```
undefined method `increment!' for nil:NilClass
```

What's the best way to handle this.I'm really confused by how to retrieve a specific object and increment it's attribute

Comment: What happens if you run Colleague.find_by_name("Ann") in rails c?

Comment: I get the correct object with name = "Ann"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, getting

```
undefined method "something" for nil:Class
```

Means that the receiver is nil ! Did you check that you object colleague1 was not nil by using a `debugger` ? If it is not nil it means that an internal *instruciton* of the `increment!` is also called increment and I have serious doubts about this.

What I find suspicious in your code is that you use `by = self.points` in you function call. In ruby you either write `:by => self.points` ( or `by: self.points`when you talk ruby 1.9.x) when a method expects a `Hash` as last argument and you know it expects `:by`as one of the keys, or just `self.points`and according to rails doc the signature of increment is:

```
increment(attribute, by = 1)
```

Which means you should use this method by calling:

```
colleague1.increment!(:bonus, self.points)
```

Comment: indeed I find with the debugger that colleague1 is nil.That's curious.Do "find_by_name" returns nil objects? I'm really confuse

Comment: `find_by_*` accessors do return `nil` objects when they don't find it. You just need to use `find_by_name!` if you want to throw an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception when necessary but you need to handle it. I think this answer is the right answer for this question. PLease consider granting this answer "the" answer of the question ;)

Comment: You right rpechayr, thanks for helping.I accept your answer.I still don't know why colleague1 is nil despite it's in the database. That's crazay!!!